# haproxy rewrite on backend to add a path for some requests to a specific domain

Tags: haproxy

I am looking to try and get haproxy to rewrite a url on the backend.  For example if the end user navigates to bitechomp.domain.com they should only see this URL but the request to the backend server needs to have the request re-written to include a path.  e.g.  bitechomp.domain.com/bitechomp

I believe I have the regex to match it, but struggling to find the syntax to then just have it add the folder path at the end.

^([a-zA-Z0-9]*/)?(bitechomp).*$

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have resolved this.

http-request set-path /bitechomp/ if { path_reg ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*/)?(bitechomp).*$ }

This works for any domain so both bitechomp.domain1.com and bitechomp.domain2.com would be re-written to bitechomp.domain1.com/bitechomp and bitechomp.domain2.com/bitechomp